# Create a unidirectional relationship between multiple different entites to a single entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, foreign-key-relationship

First things first; I've searched all over for an answer using all terms I could think of so if it's been asked in a better way I apologise.

Say I have an entity that holds some kind of non-entity-specific metadata:

```
public class MetaData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And this is referenced by separate entities:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    [???]
    public string MetaDataId { get; set; }
}

public class CompletelyDifferentEntity
{
    [???]
    public string MetaDataId { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any attribute that I could replace ??? with that would get this to work in a code-first manner? Do I have to add a MetaData property to each object just to inform EF of the relationship? I've tried `Required`, `ForeignKey`, `InverseProperty`, `Association`  attibutes (and others I've forgotten) with no luck.

If I need to fall back to the fluent API to set this up can it be set up on the metadata entity or does it need to be specified for each entity separately?

**NB**: Is the answer different if I never need to actually retrieve the MetaData properties? i.e. the id is only used for grouping?

Answer (score 0):

In order to map a foreign key relationship to the model you need a navigation property in at least one of the two related entities, i.e. either...

```
public class MetaData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SomeEntity> SomeEntities { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CompletelyDifferentEntity>
        CompletelyDifferentEntities { get; set; }
}
```

...or...

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    //...

    public int MetaDataId { get; set; }
    public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }
}

public class CompletelyDifferentEntity
{
    //...

    public int MetaDataId { get; set; }
    public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }
}
```

With those property names data annotations are not necessary because EF will recognize the `MetaDataId` as the foreign key property for the `MetaData` navigation property. The relationships will be required (not optional) because `MetaDataId` has a non-nullable type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know it will work by adding the MetaData property to these entities (as noted in the question) but I was checking if there was any way that didn't require this. It would mean adding a never-resolved property to a lot of entities which seems a shame.

Comment: @JRoughan: If you only want to have a foreign key constraint in the database you could add a sql script to a custom context initializer or add it to a code-based migration.